# JavaFX 2.0 How to set symbols for some graphs if lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);

Tags: css, graph, javafx, linechart

I draw more graphs and a lot of measurements graphs, which on lineChart looks like letter rotated H.  The number of measurements is dynamic, between 20-1000.  First I crate ObservableList  for all graphs, then I insert some values, then I add them in seriesLineChart and I add seriesLineChart to lineChart.

Problem is I have tried a lot of solutions but there isn’t any good enough. Some works fine for 5 examples for rest they crashed. I want to set circles for some graphs and to set colors of graphs.

First i crate all I need:

```
 public static LineChart<Date, Number> lineChart; //the line chart

 ObservableList<XYChart.Series<Date, Number>> seriesLineChart =           FXCollections.observableArrayList(); //I put all graphs into this

 ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Date, Number>> Errors = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
 ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Date, Number>> graphNext = FXCollections.observableArrayList(); 
 ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Date, Number>> deadLine = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
 ObservableList<XYChart.Data<Date, Number>> MaximumError =               FXCollections.observableArrayList();

 //HERE I MADE DYNAMIC MEASUREMENTS IT DEPENDES OF SOME PARAMETERS

 XYChart.Series measurement1;  
 XYChart.Series measurement1000;
```

Inserting data to all graphs except measurements

```
 for(int i=0: i<data.length; i++){
      GraphNext.add(new XYChart.Data<Date, Number>(new GregorianCalendar(nextYearCalib, Integer.valueOf(splitDate[i])-1, Integer.valueOf(splitDate[i])).getTime(),data[i]));                    
 }       //THE LENGTH OF splitDate IS LIKE data AND I DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS FOR ALL GRAPHS EXCEPT Measurements
```

Measurements goes like this:

```
 for(int i=0: i<measurementX.length; i++){  //X=1...1000(max)
      measurementX.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Date, Number>(new GregorianCalendar(Integer.valueOf(date[0]), Integer.valueOf(date[1])-1, Integer.valueOf(date[2])).getTime(),value));
```

}

Addding all  of those graphs in seriesLineChart:

```
 seriesLineChart.add(new XYChart.Series<>("SOME TEXT WHICH WILL BE TITLE IN LEGEND BELOW THE LINECHART" +, Errors));
 seriesLineChart.add(new XYChart.Series<>("SOME TEXT WHICH WILL BE TITLE IN LEGEND BELOW THE LINECHART" +, graphNext));
 seriesLineChart.add(new XYChart.Series<>("SOME TEXT WHICH WILL BE TITLE IN LEGEND BELOW THE LINECHART" +, deadLine));

 seriesLineChart.add(new XYChart.Series<>("SOME TEXT WHICH WILL BE TITLE IN LEGEND BELOW THE LINECHART" +, MaximumError));

 seriesLineChart.add(measurement1);
 ....
 seriesLineChart.add(measurement100);  //LET'S SAY FOR X=1..100
```

Adding seriesLineChart to lineChart:

```
 lineChart.setLegendVisible(true);     //sets legend below graph is visible              
 lineChart.setData(seriesLineChart);    //put seriesLineChart 
 lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);     //this instruction disable to draw circles on every graph
```

CSS file looks like:

```
 /* graph errors */
 .default-color0.chart-series-line { 
-fx-stroke:  #0181e2, white;
-fx-background-radius: 5px;
 }

 /* .default-color0.chart-legend-item-symbol{ 
-fx-stroke:  #f9d900, white; 
 }*/

 .default-color0.chart-line-symbol {
-fx-background-color: #0181e2, white;
-fx-background-radius: 5px;
 }


 /* graph next */
 .default-color1.chart-series-line {
-fx-stroke: #ffaaaa, white;
 }

 /* .default-color1.chart-legend-item-symbol{
-fx-stroke: #a9e200, white;
 } */

 .default-color1.chart-line-symbol {
-fx-background-color: #ffaaaa, white;
 }
 /* graph deadline */
 .default-color2.chart-series-line {
-fx-stroke: #a9e200, white;
-fx-background-radius: 30px;
 }

 /* .default-color2.chart-legend-item-symbol{
-fx-stroke: #ff0000, white; 
 }*/

 .default-color2.chart-line-symbol {
-fx-background-color: #a9e200, white;   
 }

 /* graph maxerror */
 .default-color3.chart-series-line {
-fx-stroke: #ff0000, white;
 }

 /* .default-color3.chart-legend-item-symbol{ 
-fx-background-color: #000000, black;
 } */

 .default-color3.chart-line-symbol {
-fx-background-color: #ff0000, white;
 }

 .default-color4.chart-series-line {
-fx-stroke: #000000, white;
 }
 .default-color4.chart-line-symbol {
-fx-background-color: #000000, white;
 }



 //AND SO ON TO THE 1000
 /* graph measurement */
 .default-color1000.chart-series-line {
-fx-stroke: #000000, white;
 }
 .default-color1000.chart-line-symbol {
-fx-background-color: #000000, white;
 }
```

.default-colorX.chart-series-line is set for color of the measurement graph
.default-color1000.chart-line-symbol is set for color of the legend of the graph

In my code I also have setup CSS file which is not default becaus I need specific colors. It has been setted before I draw on linechart.
scena.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("view/styleLineChart.css").toExternalForm());

As you can se first there are just for graphs and then other are for graphMeasurment.
Before I draw I use: lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);. But on my Errors and graphNext I need these circles. So I have analized this problems how to solve it:

1. To make circles in CSS for Errors and graphNext
2. To enable it and for others (not for Error and graphNext) in CSS to remove circles
3. I can't add more sereisLineChart on one lineChart, because than it displays the last one.

For example:

```
 lineChart.setData(seriesLineChartErrors);    
 lineChart.setCreateSymbols(true);
 lineChart.setData(seriesLineChartGraphNext);    
 lineChart.setCreateSymbols(true);
 lineChart.setData(seriesLineChart);    //all others deadilne, maxError and all mesaruments
 lineChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
```

1. I didn't fine any method to set Symbols for every graph.
2. Maybe I haven't planed well my chart, becouse of all Observebal list and ObservebelList of ObservabelLists and so on.

I also styled my legend concluding to the graphs. I use graphs and one just one measurments. Measurments from 2 to X I remove. I want to be my circles ond the legend same as realted graphs.

```
 for(Node n: lineChart.getChildrenUnmodifiable()){
if(n instanceof Legend){
    final Legend legend = (Legend) n;
    ObservableList<LegendItem> legItem = legend.g!etItems();
    for(int i=0; i<legItem.size(); i++){
        legItem.remove(5, legItem.size());
        legend.setItems(legItem);
    }
}
 }
```

I have also tried this for chart to get their CSS I it won't work:

```
 for(Node n: lineChart.getChildrenUnmodifiable()){
      if(n instanceof Chart){
     final Chart chart = (Chart) n;
     chart.getStyleClass());
     /*TO ADD SOME CODE TO MANIPULATE CSS BUT I SAW THIS CAN'T BE DONE*/                    
      }
 }
```

I have also tried something like this but I don't now how to program this beacuse of my view/styleLineChart.css. I THINK THIS WOULD BE THE BEST SOLUTION.

```
 val s = new XYChart.Series[Number, Number]();
 s.setName(measurementX);  //X=[4-1000]
 s.getNode.getStyleClass.add("series-" + seriesName);
```

And my last option would be that I would draw circles and insert them into Errors and graphNext. But I woudn't like to do this.

So I could be more understandable I adapt image with small explanations. The second is how it should look like.
I hope you coudl help me!

First image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30889532/image.png
Second image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30889532/image2.png

Comment: Doest anyone understand me what I am doing? I would be very grateful for any ideas..